# Removing duplicate shortcuts containing a specific string

Tags: string, powershell

We have a lot of users with duplicate files on their Desktop (Windows 10). I want to create a script which runs every X minutes or just once after logging on to the system.

Our users are currently seeing the following shortcuts (.lnk):

- **Dummy.lnk** *(correct shortcut, should remain unchanged)*
- **Dummy - copy.lnk** *(duplicated shortcut, should be removed)*
- **Dummy-OFFICE-QB4V70A.lnk** *(duplicated shortcut containing the name of the computer, should be removed)*

So in short I want to keep the 'original' shortcuts but I want to remove all shortcuts containing '**- copy**.lnk' and/or '**-computername**.lnk'.

I also tried using the %computername% variable but I have no idea how to implement this in my code. Every computer has a different and unique name so I can not use pre-defined computernames.

Any tips on how I can achieve this? I have tried using the code below, but this removes all .lnk (shortcut) files and not just the duplicates.

```
#(Get-ChildItem Dummy.lnk | Select-String -Pattern "OFFICE" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty path -Unique) | ForEach-Object{Remove-Item -Force -LiteralPath $_}
```

I prefer using Powershell so that I can deploy the script using Group Policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter all shortcuts you want to remove and pipe them to the `Remove-Item` cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\yourPath' -Filter '*.lnk' | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '- Copy\.lnk$' -or $_.Name -like "*$($env:Computername)*"} |
    Remove-Item
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I have tried running your code but nothing seems to be happening. Apart from changing the path, is there something else I have to check?

Comment: Maybe you want to add the -recurse switch on the Get-ChildItem cmdlet if you want to do that recursively for all subfolders inside your path?. 
I tested the script locally, it will delete all *.lnk file that ends with "- Copy" or contains your computername

Comment: @MartinBrandl why `-and` in `where-object`? shouldn't it be `-or` ?
@Codemeister try code from answer provided by martin, add `-Recurse` key and replace `-and` with `-or`
`Get-ChildItem -recurse -Path 'c:\yourPath' -Filter '*.lnk' | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '- Copy\.lnk$' -or $_.Name -like "*$($env:Computername)*"}` any output?

Comment: @TeslaGreat Great hint, you are right. I edited my answer.

Comment: It should be the right answer now(assuming codemeister doesn't need recursive search), thanks @MartinBrandl

Comment: Works like a charm now! I missed it myself but the 'or' was the fix here :-) Thank you both for the help!